# It doesn't work under "alert condition" when writing auto trade messages

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to ask a lot of developers.

This alert_message works fine in auto trading.

```
if entrycondition
   strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=entry_size, limit=r_close, comment="Entry", alert_message='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"ADA/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":'+str.tostring(entry_size)+',"token":"1234"}:MVT')
```

I want to write message like below code in stratagy.

```
useentryalert    = input(defval=true, title="Use Entry Alert", group="Alert Messages")
entrystring      = input.string(title="Entry Alert Message", defval='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"ADA/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":'+str.tostring(entry_size)+',"token":"1234"}:MVT', confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")

if entry_condition and useentryalert
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=entry_size, limit=close, comment="Entry", alert_message=entrystring)
```

However, I wrote the same message as above, but it does not apply to the automatic trading system.

I think there is a problem with the str.tostring part, but I can't fix it.

I need help.

Comment: What deos not work? Do you get to see your alert message or it does not trigger at all? If you get the alerts, what message do you get and what message do you expect? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: The code I wrote is alerted normally.  And if I directly write ‘TVM~~~~~’ in strategy.order(alert_message) the system works normally in auto trading system, but if I put the same ‘TVM~~~~~’ in ‘entrystring’ and use it, the system does not work in auto trading system.

Comment: I use the same message, but in this condition // entrystring      = input.string(title="Entry Alert Message", defval='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"ADA/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":'+str.tostring(entry_size)+',"token":"1234"}:MVT', confirm=false, group="Alert Messages") // the message is not applied in the automatic trading system.  Messages are triggered normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass function calls to a `defval` argument of the `input.*` functions (except in some cases where a function can return a constant value).
But you can make your own placeholders to use in inputs, or concatenate the text of the alert message separately, using inputs for fields that the user must fill in and expressions calculated in the code

Example with own placeholders:

```
useentryalert    = input(defval=true, title="Use Entry Alert", group="Alert Messages")
entrystring      = input.text_area(title="Entry Alert Message", defval='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"ADA/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":{{entrySize}},"token":"1234"}:MVT', confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")

alertMsg = str.replace_all(entrystring, "{{entrySize}}", str.tostring(entry_size))
if entry_condition and useentryalert
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=entry_size, limit=close, comment="Entry", alert_message=alertMsg)
```

Example with concatenation:

```
useentryalert = input(defval=true, title="Use Entry Alert", group="Alert Messages")
account       = input.string(title="account", defval="*", confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")
token         = input.string(title="token", defval="1234", confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")

alertMsg = 'TVM:{' + str.format('"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"{0}","symbol":"ADA/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":{1},"token":"{2}"', account, str.tostring(entry_size), token) + '}:MVT'
if entry_condition and useentryalert
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=entry_size, limit=close, comment="Entry", alert_message=alertMsg)
```